# Does increasing the tempdb file size require a restart

Tags: sql-server, tempdb

I want to alter tempdb as such (i am increasing the size)

```
USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [tempdb] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'temp2', SIZE = 10240KB )
GO
ALTER DATABASE [tempdb] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'temp3', SIZE = 10240KB )
GO
ALTER DATABASE [tempdb] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'temp4', SIZE = 10240KB )
GO
ALTER DATABASE [tempdb] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'tempdev', SIZE = 10240KB )
GO
```

Will this require me to restart SQL server?

Comment: Are you increasing or decreasing the size?

Comment: Increasing the size

Comment: Increasing wont require restart but make sure that autogrowth is no in %.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Increasing the size does not require a restart.

A small example on my dev environment

```
USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [tempdb] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'temp2', SIZE = 4096MB )
GO
GO
ALTER DATABASE [tempdb] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'tempdev', SIZE = 4096MB )
GO
```

From:

[image]

To:

[image]

---

If you are decreasing the size with `MODIFY FILE` it would require a restart.
If you want to decrease the size immediately, you would have to start shrinking (not ideal).

Comment: Does the TempDB filecount increase while staying at the same filesize for current files require restart?